Query with "NOT IN" not returning any result
Im trying to get all the results where there's no operation on a certain year(let's say current year), but for some reason I can't get any result. I tried making a testing table but I get the results as expected, so I dont know what I'm doing wrong, it's driving me mad. Maybe there's something wrong with my data?
I'm pasting the code to creating the table hopping anyone can help me
 CREATE TABLE `factura` (
   `ID` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `client` decimal(5,0) DEFAULT NULL,
   `date` date DEFAULT '2000-01-01',
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
 );
 INSERT INTO `factura` VALUES (249,4,'2023-11-24'),(263,2,'2023-11-25'),(281,3,'2023-12-14'),(282,5,'2023-12-14'),(293,6,'2024-01-15'),(297,7,'2024-02-02'),(298,NULL,'2024-02-02'),(299,8,'2023-10-02'),(300,9,'2023-04-02'),(301,10,'2024-02-03'),(306,11,'2024-02-07'),(307,12,'2024-02-07'),(308,13,'2024-02-07'),(309,14,'2024-02-07'),(310,15,'2024-02-07'),(319,16,'2024-02-07'),(320,17,'2024-02-07'),(321,NULL,'2024-02-07'),(322,18,'2024-02-11'),(323,19,'2024-02-11'),(331,20,'2024-04-01'),(332,20,'2024-04-04'),(333,20,'2024-03-18'),(334,21,'2024-03-19'),(335,22,'2024-04-12'),(336,23,'2024-04-12'),(337,24,'2024-04-12'),(338,25,'2024-04-12'),(339,26,'2024-04-12'),(340,27,'2024-04-12'),(341,28,'2024-04-12'),(342,29,'2024-04-12'),(344,31,'2024-04-12'),(345,32,'2024-04-12'),(346,33,'2024-04-12'),(347,34,'2024-04-12'),(348,35,'2024-04-12'),(349,36,'2024-04-12'),(350,37,'2024-04-12'),(351,38,'2024-04-12'),(352,39,'2024-04-12'),(353,40,'2024-04-12'),(354,41,'2024-04-12'),(355,42,'2024-04-12'),(356,43,'2024-04-12'),(357,44,'2024-04-12'),(358,45,'2024-04-12'),(359,46,'2024-04-12'),(360,47,'2024-04-12'),(361,48,'2024-04-12'),(362,49,'2024-04-12'),(363,50,'2024-04-12'),(364,51,'2024-04-12'),(365,52,'2024-04-12'),(366,53,'2024-04-12'),(367,54,'2024-04-12'),(368,55,'2024-04-12'),(369,56,'2024-04-12'),(370,57,'2024-04-12'),(371,58,'2024-04-12'),(372,59,'2024-04-12'),(373,60,'2024-04-12'),(374,61,'2024-04-12'),(381,2,'2023-04-12'),(382,62,'2024-04-12'),(383,63,'2024-04-12'),(384,64,'2024-04-12'),(391,65,'2024-04-12'),(392,66,'2024-04-12'),(394,1,'2023-01-01'),(395,1,'2023-01-01'),(397,1,'2023-01-01'),(400,67,'2023-01-01'),(401,68,'2023-01-01'),(402,30,'2023-01-01'),(408,1,'2014-01-01'),(409,1,'2014-01-01'),(410,1,'2014-01-01'),(411,1,'2014-01-01'),(412,69,'2014-01-01'),(413,70,'2014-01-01'),(414,71,'2014-01-01');

And the query that is not working
 SELECT `ID`,`client` FROM `factura` WHERE `client` NOT IN (SELECT `client` FROM `factura` WHERE year(`date`) = '2024')

I tried with a fresh separate table, with new data and it works properly. Also created the same table on a different schema (with this pasted data) and doesnt work.

Thanks a lot whoever post the link to the similar threat! The solution was  as simple as adding "and client is not null"
